# Why won't my first line be printed from my txt file?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, encryption

I want my code to take the first line of my `.txt` file & print it a certain way, I thought I had the right idea but nothing's happening inside the console.

Here's my `.txt` file:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZOOOOOOO
12345678912345678912345678912
```

Here's my `.java` file:

```
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptDecrypt {

    public static void encrypt() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cryptographyTextFile.txt"));
        String line = in.readLine();
        int iterator = 0;
        char[][] table = new char[6][5];

        // fill array
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {        
                table[i][j] = line.charAt(iterator++);
            }
        }

        // print array
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        encrypt();
    }
}
```

I want my code to only take the first line from my `.txt` file and print it out like so:

```
ABCDE
GHIJK
MNOPQ
STUVW
XYZOO
OOOOO
```

Here's the `error` I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:    String index out of range: 29
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at EncryptDecrypt.encrypt(EncryptDecrypt.java:14)
at EncryptDecrypt.main(EncryptDecrypt.java:28)
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are having? Have you tried running through it with a debugger?

Comment: Try surrounding your code with a `try-catch` and see if there is any I/O error thrown, it is also good practice.

Comment: Copying your code of your encrypt-method and creating a file like yours, it works for me as expected.

Comment: @ThomasBöhm It's not working for me for some reason

Comment: Do you really want to remove every sixth char? Because it looks like you do that everytime beside in the second last line, there there is no char missing.

Comment: Are you sure your input-file looks exactly like this? The error-message looks like you are reading the second line, which has only 29 chars, which would lead to this error.

Comment: The error tells you, that your are accessing a char of the string, that is out of the range (too high or low)

Comment: Your output has no pattern!

Comment: Code works for me,  as is. Not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: Also,  the actual output I'm getting is different from what you claim to be expecting

Answer (score 0):

Your output differs (because it works) from your desired output, because you didn't filter every 6th character. I think that is what you are trying to do so...

I think I found your solution by using modulo you can search on every 6th number. i.e. 6 % 6 = 0 while 5 % 6 = 1

```
// fill array
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if ((iterator + 1) % 6 == 0) {
                iterator++;
                j--;
            } else {
                //System.out.println(i+" "+ j + " " +iterator + " " + line.charAt(iterator));
                char t = line.charAt(iterator++);
                table[i][j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
```

also add 2 more character to the string. line.charAt(iterator++) is searching java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. that's why you are receiving the error

Answer (score 0):

The native `substring()` method can be your help with some conditions and increments

```
        String str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZOOOOOOO";

        int ite = str.length() / 5;
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        while ( i < ite ) {

            System.out.println( str.substring( j, ( j += 5 ) ) );
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println( str.substring( ite * 5, str.length() % 5 + ite * 5 ) );
```